# Count() in query returns doubled value (12 instead of 6)

Tags: mysql

This query will return a value of 12 for reg_count if

```
cp.field_kurs_kategorie_tid IN ('28', '30', '39', '34', '31')
```

has more than three entries.

```
cp.field_kurs_kategorie_tid IN ('28', '30', '39')
```

returns the correct result of 6. Any ideas why this is happening?

This is the full query:

```
    SELECT n.nid AS nid, n.title AS title, r.entity_id AS entity_id, tr.field_lifestyle_tid AS field_lifestyle_tid, tn.name AS name, ct.field_kurstyp_tid AS field_kurstyp_tid, cp.field_kurs_kategorie_tid AS field_kurs_kategorie_tid, pn.name AS pn_name, ga.field_grund_der_absage_value AS field_grund_der_absage_value, cd.field_kursdatum_value AS field_kursdatum_value, cd.field_kursdatum_value2 AS field_kursdatum_value2, COUNT(r.entity_id) AS reg_count
FROM 
l_node n
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_registration r ON n.nid = r.entity_id AND r.state != 'waitlist'
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_field_data_field_lifestyle tr ON n.nid = tr.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_field_data_field_kurstyp ct ON n.nid = ct.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_field_data_field_kurs_kategorie cp ON n.nid = cp.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_taxonomy_term_data tn ON tr.field_lifestyle_tid = tn.tid
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_taxonomy_term_data pn ON cp.field_kurs_kategorie_tid = pn.tid
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_field_data_field_grund_der_absage ga ON ga.entity_id = n.nid AND ga.field_grund_der_absage_value IS NOT NULL AND ga.field_grund_der_absage_value != '0'
LEFT OUTER JOIN l_field_data_field_kursdatum cd ON n.nid = cd.entity_id AND cd.delta = 0
WHERE  (n.type = 'location') AND (tr.field_lifestyle_tid IN  ('19')) AND (ct.field_kurstyp_tid IN  ('26')) AND (cp.field_kurs_kategorie_tid IN  ('28', '30', '39', '34', '31')) AND (cd.field_kursdatum_value BETWEEN '2016-05-02' AND '2016-05-04 23:00') 
GROUP BY r.entity_id
```

Any ideas what the problem is? 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are joining using LEFT OUTER JOIN and the table you are COUNTing (l_registration) is not the left-most table, then depending on your data you are returning multiple rows from l_registration, i.e. one for each record that links to a selected l_node record.

Comment: Hi and thanks! I've modiefied my query now to have my intial call set to 'l_registration', and joining l_node on it. Still, no changes in the result - returns 12 again. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's difficult without seeing the data.  I would strip down your SQL to the smallest possible which has the correct result, and slowly add each join and see which one is causing the problem.